# Repository Pattern with ISession in Constructor - unit test

Tags: unit-testing, repository

I have a repository

```
EmployeeRepository:IEmployeeRepository

EmployeeRepository(Isession session) {}
```

If I want to write test class to test Save and delete methods in repository,

```
[Test]
public void Test_Save()
{
  //??? - how should i create an instance of my repository? I am not sure how should I pass session in my test class? 
  _repository.Save(entity);
}
```

please help.

Comment: You have a TestSession that implements ISession?

Answer (score 0):

I would mock out a Session to hand to the repository. make sure your testing the repository and not your network/database :D

Comment: Can you show an example. I am looking to do something similar. I want to test the session logic and repository logic but not actually hook up to a DB. I have mocked a repository but that means I am not mocking the real repository.